# attach paypal account after login to my website for future payments

Tags: php, paypal, authentication, paypal-sandbox, payment

i want to attach paypal account to my website after paypal login so that we only asks the user for login at first time .

So that we can send payments to his paypal account in future without asking him to login again from our site.

Process what i want

1)User comes to my website click on login using paypal

2)after login he is redirected to my website after redirection we store some of his details so that we can use this in future

Now main part why i need this

3)after sometime 2 weeks or 1 month user gets $50 from our website to his account and he wants to withdraw that amount using paypal.what i want to do here is to send $50 to his paypal account without asking the user to login again on paypal

Can somebody tell me how can i do it.

i have read Paypal login api but it says it works like facebook and twitter login not the way i want it to.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Mass payment service from PayPal, where you can transfer the amount to your customer's PayPal account. You can send to many customer at once, only you need is their account mail ID. For more details about Mass payment kindly 
Click [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/mass-pay/)